# Styling the last <li> <a>

Tags: html, css, styles

I stucked at this part. I have a menu in HTML like this:

```
<nav> 
<ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Item1_1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item1_1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item1_1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item1_1</a></li>
                            <li><a id="last" href="#">Last</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS is this:

```
nav {

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;    

}

 nav ul ul li a #last {

border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;

}    


nav ul ul {

display: none;

}

nav ul li:hover > ul {

    display: block;
 }

nav ul {    

background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fffff 0%, #fffff 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 100%);    
padding: 0px;    
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
width: 100%;    
text-align: center;

}

nav ul:after {

content: ""; 
clear: both; 
display: block;


}


nav ul li {

width: 20%;
float: left;
text-align: center;


}

nav ul li:hover {

border-top-left-radius: 1em;
border-top-right-radius: 1em;
background: #4b545f;
background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);        

}

nav ul li:hover a {

color: #fff;    

}


nav ul li a {

font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 0.9em;
font-weight: bold;
display: block; 
padding: 0.9em;
color: #000000; 
text-decoration: none;    

}


nav ul ul {

width: 20%;
background: #5f6975;
border-radius: 0px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;


}

nav ul ul li {

font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
float: none;
width: 100%;    
border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
position: relative;  

}

nav ul ul li a {

font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 0.7em;
width: 89%;
padding: 15px 10px;        

}

nav ul ul li a:hover {

background: #4b545f;

}
```

As You can see there is an id="last" for the last item at the list, because I want to this item have a rounderd bottom border (left and right side aswell). But I have no idea why its not working :(. Its my first post so sorry for my english, and for the long post aswell :) Plase help me, thank You!

Comment: Maybe not really an answer to your question, but you might want to take a look at [pseudo-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes) like `:last-child` and `:last-of-kind` (and their support in the browsers you need to support :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For id you need to make css like this:

```
nav ul ul li a#last
```

noticed the difference? the #last is combined with the a.

Comment: Thank You, Its works :). But only on hover :(. The bg of the last won't be rounded.

Comment: @Balu you mean the ul background? then you need to make border-radius on the ul not the a or li

Comment: Regarding i don't able to write it in english, I show you :). Here is the page: http://www.grupolobo.hu/new_site/1_5/ and I want the rounded bottom for Márkáink / Project One. Thank You again!

Comment: @Balu on the nav ul ul add border-radius: 0 0 x x; x = value you want. and on the nav ul ul li remove the border-bottom. with this just adjust the :hover.

Comment: I did it but no luck, it do nothing at all :(. BTW thank You for the help. I'll try to make it somehow :)

Comment: @Balu you tried nav ul ul { border-radius: 0 0 17px 17px } and it didnt worked?

Comment: Yes, I tride excatly what You wrote, but it did nothing. I'll try it in a different way and I'll tell you if it was good :) Ty!

Comment: nav ul li ul {
    
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    
} <-- THIS IS IT!!! :D

Not perfect, but its closer to my exception :)

Comment: So, I found the solution here it is:  
#last {
    
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;    
    
}

nav ul li ul {
    
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    
}

Thank all of You for the help guys!

Answer (score 4):

Since #last is unique, all you need is:

```
#last {
   ...your css..
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Its works aswell, great tip :). But only on hover :(. The bg of the last won't be rounded.

Comment: `#last` is unique, but in the stylesheet and on other pages, `#last` might be a different element. This would then open up a can of worms over whether one should use `nav ul ul li a#last` or just `#last`

Comment: @Diodeus you font get it, imagine a css file with more than 200 lines, now try to discover from which element the #last comes from...

Comment: It's easy, since IDs are unique, you just search for that ID in the code. There is absolutely no need to prefix ANY id selector.

Comment: It's all about CSS SPECIFICITY. Read up: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: how you know what element it comes from just looking at the css, or open the html file to search it for or use the "redundant" path to make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

`a #last` means "the element with the ID of `"last"` that is a child of an `<a>` tag.

You don't need the space there.  `a#last` means "an `<a>` tag with the ID of `"last"`.

Actually, since IDs are supposed to be unique, you can just use `#last`, without the `a` (or even the rest of the elements before it).